# Why am I getting a 404 'App [my-project-id] was not found. The app preview may have expired.' trying push notifications on my Actions on Google?

Tags: push-notification, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm following the [official instructions](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) on how to send push notifications to users that gives their permission.

I'm able to follow all the instructions until this code
appMap.set('finish.push.setup', function(app)) {

```
 if (app.isPermissionGranted()) {
    const intent = app.getArgument('UPDATE_INTENT');
    const userID = app.getArgument('UPDATES_USER_ID');
    // code to save intent and userID in your db
    app.tell("Ok, I'll start alerting you");
  } else {
    app.tell("Ok, I won't alert you");
  }
}
```

the `app.getArgument('UPDATE_INTENT')` return `undefined` and checking the JSON it looks like it doesn't contain the intent at all but I have only one intent configured for updates so I hardcoded it's name in the code.
I got a userID and I hardcoded it too in the code.

Then I followed the instructions to get a service account key and I saved the JSON key locally.

Then the nasty problems begins.
I installed the required packages with `npm install googleapis request --save` and copied the code

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const key = require(PATH_TO_KEY);

let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email, null, key.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation'],
  null
);

jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
  // code to retrieve target userId and intent
  let notif = {
    userNotification: {
      title: '',
    },
    target: {
      userId: '',
      intent: ''
    }
  }

  request.post('https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send', {
    'auth': {
      'bearer': tokens.access_token
     },
    'json': true,
    'body': { 'customPushMessage': notif }
  }, function(err,httpResponse,body) {
     console.log(httpResponse.statusCode + ': ' + httpResponse.statusMessage)
  });
});
```

I edited it setting the right path to my key and edited the notification property with fixed values (the same title configured in the action, the userID returned by dialogflow and the name of my intent).

Then I noticed that the code is missing a `const request = require('request');` and the line

```
let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
```

gives an error so I changed to

```
let jwtClient = new google.google.auth.JWT(
```

I added a `console.log('body', body);` just to get more data and I got

```
body { error:
   { code: 404,
     message: 'App [my-project-id] was not found. The app preview may have expired.',
     status: 'NOT_FOUND' } }
```

Am I doing something wrong or the documentation has other errors I still have to catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add **locale** at target object:

```
   let notif = {
    userNotification: {
      title: '',
    },
    target: {
      userId: '',
      intent: '',
      locale: ''
    }
  }
```

For locale follow IETF BCP-47 language code as described [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#target).

By default Google Actions use en-US language, and I figure out you are using a differente language code, so the system reply that cannot found us version of your application.